# Not getting all page ratings via Facebook Graph, getting small difference

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I'm using FB graph to load all the ratings of my FB page so I can show them on my website. This way people can write their opinions on FB, and it will appear on the site as well.

What I've encountered now is that FB graph returns 47 ratings, but when I visit the FB page there are 49 ratings.

At first, I thought this was related to privacy settings of 2 users, making the rating non-public, but when I visit the FB page as a logged-out user, the same 49 ratings appear.

As a result, I cannot show the 47 reviews on the webpage, as people will feel I've tampered with the reviews, leaving 2 out.

I've already played with the paging and limit parameters, but no matter what I try, I can only get 47 out of 49 ratings from graph.

I'm using the page token that I obtained from an admin user, so no problem there. The ratings are loaded using this query:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/{PAGE-ID}/ratings?fields=review_text,reviewer,created_time,has_review,has_rating,rating&limit=9999999&access_token={ACCESS-TOKEN}

The limit of 9999999 doesn't make a difference. I've tried without limit and combining multiple pages, but the end result is always 47 instead of 49.

I'm out of ideas what could be the cause of this.